# Can't pass a props to child component inside an iteration

Tags: reactjs, ecmascript-6

i got a problem when i try to pass a props to child component inside map iteration in my parent component. it always show a message notify that

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'props' of undefined

can someone help me figure out what wrong in my code? i already try to pass it through a local state too, then still got an error.

here is my code :
My Parent Component

```
import React from 'react';
import { TabContent, TabPane, Nav, NavItem, NavLink, Card, Button, CardTitle, CardText, Row, Col } from 'reactstrap';
import classnames from 'classnames';

import PeriodicSetup from './PeriodicSetup';
import PeriodicDataTable from './PeriodicDataTable';

import {connect} from 'react-redux';
import store from '../../store/store';

class SetupPage extends React.Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.toggle = this.toggle.bind(this);
        this.state = {
            activeTab: 0,
        };
    }

    toggle(tab) {
        if (this.state.activeTab !== tab) {
            this.setState({
                activeTab: tab
            });
        }
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <Nav tabs>
                    {this.props.SetupTabTitles.map((data, i)=>
                            <NavItem>
                                <NavLink className={classnames({ active: this.state.activeTab === i})} onClick={() => {this.toggle(i); }}>
                                    {data.tabTitle}
                                </NavLink>
                            </NavItem>
                        )}
                </Nav>

                <TabContent activeTab={this.state.activeTab}>
                    {this.props.SetupTabTitles.map(function(data, i) {
                        if(data.tabTitle == 'Tasks'){
                            return (
                                <TabPane tabId={i}>
                                    test
                                </TabPane>
                            )
                        }else if(data.tabTitle == 'Periodic'){
                            return (
                                <TabPane tabId={i}>
                                    <PeriodicSetup />
                                    <PeriodicDataTable periodicData = {this.props.periodicList}/>
                                </TabPane>
                            )
                        }
                    })}
                </TabContent>
            </div>
        );
    }

}

function mapStateToProps(state){
    return {
        SetupTabTitles : state.component.SetupTabTitles,
        periodicList : state.setup.periodicList
    };
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(SetupPage);
```

My Child Component :

```
import React from 'react';
const {Table, Column, Cell} = require('fixed-data-table');

export default class PeriodicDataTable extends React.Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
    }

     render() {
        return (
            <div>
                test
            </div>
        )
    }
}
```

The Condition in my code,

> this.props.periodicList

already have an array value, and everything is working well if i commend out my

```
<PeriodicDataTable periodicData = {this.props.periodicList}/>
```

or i move it out from the iteration, it works. but i still don't know why it got an error if i put it inside an iteration.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need pass your map callback function with explicit passing to `this` that refer to the React component, not the callback function that has no property called `props`, to be like this:

```
{this.props.SetupTabTitles.map(this.renderTabTitles.bind(this))}
```

then add a method in your class as follow:

```
renderTabTitles(data, i) {
    if(data.tabTitle == 'Tasks') {
        return (
            <TabPane tabId={i}>
                test
            </TabPane>
        )
    } else if(data.tabTitle == 'Periodic') {
        return (
            <TabPane tabId={i}>
                <PeriodicSetup />
                <PeriodicDataTable periodicData = {this.props.periodicList}/>
            </TabPane>
        )
    }
}
```